# How can I load byte strings into a file and put them in another location (python)

Tags: python

Sorry if that doesn't describes what I need to do but i need to make a program or script that goes to the 'Pictures' folder on a windows system grab a picture (I assume using a byte string) store it in a file (pickle or...) and load the file into another folder...

long story short, I have a program that would be complete if I could add a function that can be run on a computer (mine or anyone with my program installed) go to there 'pictures' folder on a windows os and take a picture image file and store them in a transportable file (pickle) then take that file and unload(pickle) it on my/another computer using a function preferably the same one

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: why isn't an image file "transportable"? why add unnecessary complexity?

Comment: not homework, did it for a friend

Comment: The image in the Pictures folder is already a byte string stored in a file. Just copy it to the desired destination. i.e open the target file and the source file in binary mode and read then write the bytes from one to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my earlier comment you could write something that `open()`ed both the source image file and a destination file in binary mode, and then use the file `read()` and `write()` methods to copy the bytes from one file to the other.

However that's a somewhat low-level approach would be reinventing the wheel.

A better alternative would be to just use one of the existing `copyfile...()` or even higher-level `copy...()` file copying functions in the `shutil` module, which you can read about [here](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#module-shutil).